# QGIS export attribute table to CSV and keep value relation

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, csv

If I export my joined table to CSV I get the numeric id value instead of the value relation name from the joined table.

Can I export my table with the value relation value?

Comment: Haven't tested this but have you tried selecting all features in the _Attribute Table_ , clicking the **Copy selected rows to clipboard** and then pasting it into a csv document?

Comment: Try installing  the mmqgis plugin, you get more options for exporting to csv

Comment: Joseph, that is what I tried first but it did not work neither. juls, forgot about mmqgis, will try it.

Comment: I solved it in the end by doing a join in my postgis db I use instead . But I will give juls suggestion a try too for future reference

Comment: I tried the mmqgis tool just now as well. The export did not keep the value relation in the csv file neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.
To date it does not seem possible to export the attribute table to a csv and keep the value relation at the same time.

There is however a way of accomplish it by using a your SQL client. I just made a join between the Child and the Parent table to display the value instead of the numeric id number.

Note: If you are working with *.shp you can always import them into spatial lite to do the join in SQL language.